# Why The Content Is Repeating 6 Times Even After Making A For Loop For 3 Times

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

This Is The Code Which Of Node JS Of A Route[Check The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeU6H.png)

```
text.find().then((result)=>{
        // let posts = {Uname: result[randomness].username, Tpost: result[randomness].postText, Likes: result[randomness].likes, Postid: result[randomness]._id}
        let tweets = '';
        for(let i = 0; i<3; i++){
            randomness = Math.floor(Math.random()*result.length)
            tweets += `
            <div class="tweet">
            <div class="pro-pic">A</div>
            <div class="tweet-content">
                <div class="texter"><b>${result[randomness].username}</b></div>
                <div class="post-content">${result[randomness].postText}</div>
                <form class="function-buttons" method="post" action="/like/${result[randomness]._id}">
                    <button class="heart" type="submit">
                        <div class="ac-animated-heart">
                            <div class="circle1"></div>
                            <div class="circle2"></div>
                            <div class="square"></div>
                        </div> 
                    </button>
                    <input name="postId" type="text" style="display:none" value="${result[randomness]._id}">
                    <input name="like" value="${result[randomness].likes}" readonly class="likes">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
                    `;
        }
        // console.log(tweets)
        let posts = {content: tweets}
        res.status(200).render('index.pug',posts)
    })
```

Comment: Theres something wrong on the tag there is `>`

Comment: `<input>` should be auto-closing tags (`<input />`)